# use subsonic 2.x and 3.x in the same project

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Is it possible to mix them?  I'm asking because I have a big project that uses Subsonic 2.x generated classes (in a compiled dll) but would like to start using 3.x for new stuff.

I tried it last night with a project where I had references to both subsonic.dll and subsonic.core.dll but that didn't work with ambiguous references, etc.  So removed 2.x  and then got an issue with my older compiled subsonic generated classes in that they needed Subsonic 2.1 to run.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm... I think there's a small chance that you might be able to do this, but you'd need to use the full qualifying class names (namespace.class) for a lot of code because there might be naming conflicts. It wouldn't be easy to do and definitely not recommended. (It might not can even be done.)

You can't move from 2.x to 3.x without doing a lot of recoding. I have a bunch of big projects in 2.2 and after trying to update to 3.0, I ran into some issues so I've decided to keep them in 2.2. I'd love to upgrade to 3.0 and use the new stuff, too, but I don't have the time (right now) to recode the stuff that changed between 2.x and 3.0.

I do recommend updating to 2.2. There shouldn't be any backwards compatibility issues between 2.1 and 2.2. I was able to update to 2.2 by just changing out my reference.

Just curious, are you using ActiveRecord or Repo implementation?

You only have 2 options:

1. stay in 2.1/2.2
2. update your code to 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd follow up here and let people know that I was able to get this to work.  What i chose to do was to edit the Subsonic 2 source code and put it into a Subsonic2 namespace (everything), recompile to subsonic2.dll, etc.  Had to modify the web.config slightly, then went and modified my old code to reference subsonic2, etc.

Am now able to mix both Subsonic 2 and 3 in the same project.

Gerry

Comment: Currently Trying to do this. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Jim--I'm using ActiveRecord.  The 2.x is in one namespace and 3.x would be in another.  However, I guess the question is whether the 2.x can be compiled to run with the 3.x runtime.

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: I would say no, but I haven't tested it. There's a lot of differences between 2.x and 3.0, especially in regards to ActiveRecord. You'll have to recode a bunch of stuff in 3.0 that was originally included by default in 2.x.