# Can I run Subsonic 2.1 and 3.0 side by side

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have a small code base using Subsonic 2.1 in my project. I would like to start using Subsonic 3.0 as soon as possible. But I don't currently have resources to convert the 2.1 implementation. Is it possible to start using 3.0 for new code and leave the 2.1 code running. Will I have any special conflicts. Anything I should watch for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this. There would be too many conflicts with the naming of the namespaces and classes.

Very similar question asked a couple of days ago at
[use subsonic 2.x and 3.x in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341151/use-subsonic-2-x-and-3-x-in-the-same-project)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't run them side by side. Depending on what you're using (ActiveRecord/RepositoryRecord and Query/SqlQuery) migration difficulty will vary. If you're using RepositoryRecord and only SqlQuery queries the migration to the LinqTemplates is not that complicated.